# How to find frequency in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am having some issues with SQL code, specifically in finding the frequency of an ID.

My table looks like

```
Num  ID
136   23
1427  45
1415  67
1416  23
7426  45
4727  12
4278  67
...
```

I would need to see the frequency of ID, when this has more or equal 2 same values.

For example: 23, 45 and 67 in the table above.

I have tried as follows:

```
Select distinct *, count(*)
From table_1
Group by 1,2
Having count(*) >2
```

But it is wrong.
I need distinct, as I do not want any duplicates in Num.
I think I should you a counter to reset when the value of the next rows is different from the previous one and report the frequency (1, 2, 3, and so on), then select values greater or equal to 2, but Indo not know how to do it in Sql.
Could you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: When you print 23 (ID), your Num which value must acquire? 136, 1416, the sum, or you don't want to show? Please add your wished result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ID` only in `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS No_frequency
FROM table t
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Note : If you have duplicate `num` then use `distinct` :

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT num) >= 2;
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh. How could I check their frequency? I would like also to know how many rows are the sames. For example, 23 has frequency = 2 ...

Comment: Do  you think I could also have information on num?i would need this list for further analysis.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can try this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(1)
FROM table_1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
```

In this way you have the ID's with 2 or more occurences and the number of occurences

**EDIT**
I suppose you are using MySql but add your DBMS in your question, so, try this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) as FREQUENCY, GROUP_CONCAT(NUM)
FROM table_1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
```

Comment: This would be perfect if I could also include the condition for distinct num.

Comment: Thank you Joe. No, I am using SQL Teradata assistant, not MySQL

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
    SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS Frq FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY ID 
    HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2 
    ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC
```